# Calling Base Class Constructors in C++

Tags: c++

Is this a legal way of calling a base class constructor.

The Base Class is as follows

```
class base_class
{
    public:
    base_class(int x, int y);    
    protected:
    int a;
    int b;
};

base_class::base_class(int x,int y)
{
    a=x;
    b=y;
}
```

The Derived class is a follows

```
class derived_class: public base_class
{
    public:
    derived_class(int x,int y,int z);
    protected:
    int c;
};
derived_class:: derived_class(int x,int y,int z):base_class(x,y)  /*Edited and included the scope resolution operator*/
{
    c=z;
}
```

Is this way of defining a derived class constructor legal in C++, if yes how is the base class constructor called?

Comment: other than the syntax error at `derived_class: dervied_class(...)` (u missed an extra colon), it looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct (and only) way to initialise your base class(es) if you're invoking a non-default constructor -- if you add the second colon to the scope-resolution operator, of course.

It is more usual to initialise **all** of your members in the "initializer list" (the section between the colon and the function body), like so:

```
derived_class::derived_class(int x,int y,int z):
    base_class(x, y),
    c(z)
{
}
```

...where `c(z)` initialises your `int c` to the value of `z`.

Comment: Technically, a base class will be initialized using the default constructor if you don't do it explicitly. </pedantic>

Comment: True enough. `base_class` doesn't have a default constructor in this case :)

Comment: I know (and mentioned that). Just thought it should be in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you meant

```
derived_class::derived_class(int x,int y,int z):base_class(x,y)   
//            |
//     scope resolution operator
```

then yes. It's not only *a* legal way, it's *the* only way to explicitly call a base constructor for the current object.

Unless you do this, the default constructor is called implicitly. In your case, the base class doesn't have a default constructor, so you'd get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct way and infact the only way of calling i.e, base class constructor before derived class.